# Black screen during boot, cannot see information

Tags: boot, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo [ThinkStation P330](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/workstations/p-series/ThinkStation-P330-Tower/p/WMD00000364) with Windows installed. When I press the power button, the screen (connected with DisplayPort) stays black until the windows login screen appears.

That makes it difficult to boot from USB stick. I just guessed F12 to be correct and pressed that during the black screen period, it appears to work (it doesn't boot automatically into Windows), but the screen stays black so I have a hard time doing anything.

How can I understand what is going on?

Comment: There's no ThinkStation tag for the towers, only thinkpad for the laptops. Since the architecture is similar, I've used that one.

Comment: Not a real solution, but as a temporary workaround, try connecting the screen using a different type of cable (e.g. HDMI, DVI or VGA). It seems that DisplayPorts sometimes have this kind of issue. If that's the case, it's also possible that a change in BIOS settings or a BIOS update would fix it. [(related bug at Lenovo support)](https://support.lenovo.com/en/solutions/ht074529).

Comment: I'm not sure which model of thinkstation you have, but if it has a dedicated graphics card in it, It's possible that during boot the output is piping to onboard graphics and the displayport is only activated once windows boots and detects the display as being connected. If this is the issue (and there is onboard graphics as well as a dedicated card) you should be able to connect a monitor to different output on the machine (VGA/DVI/HDMI) have a poke around in BIOS and select which graphics output to boot with. **Could you add the model of thinkstation, or a link to your build?**

Comment: @Smock It appears to be a P330: https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/workstations/p-series/ThinkStation-P330-Tower/p/WMD00000364

Comment: Looks like there's 7 displayport sockets on the back of that. . I'll add an answer so I can add a picture

Comment: Had the same issue on P340. Here are the key-presses needed to reset the BIOS: power on, F1 (for 10s), Esc, F9, Enter, F10, Enter. Note: this worked on graphical BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are 7 display port sockets on the back of your PC (P330 thinkstation) - could you confirm the picture below matches the back of your PC?

[image]

The red & blue circled ones look like onboard ports, and the 4 black circled ones look like a dedicated card.

**If your monitor is plugged into one of the 4 *black-circled* display-port sockets:**

Try plugging it into one of the red-circled ones. (or blue if that doesn't work either)

If you can see and access BIOS when it's plugged into a red/blue circled one, you may be able to find somewhere to select which one (onboard or dedicated), or both,  is used during the boot sequence. If not you may need to disable the onboard graphics.

**If your monitor is plugged into the red/blue circled ones currently:**

Plug it into one of the black circled ones. In theory, it should default to the dedicated graphics card during boot if there is one present (see forum thread link below)

**It's also possible your machine is booting faster than the monitor can sync or has a fast-boot/no display option**

From the thread linked at the bottom (emphasis my own):

> P330 boots fast....like really fast.  If you have a display connected that is slow to sync, it could very likely boot right past the BIOS setup hotkey message and be past that before your display ever really lights up.  The workaround for this is that after you press the power button to turn the system on, keep an eye on the numlock key on the keyboard.  **When that numlock LED lights up, BIOS has enumerated the keyboard and it can accept input.  At that point, start tapping the `F1` key (maybe once per second is enough).**  If you do that, once your display syncs and lights up, it'll likely be sitting at the BIOS setup screen.

---

*Side note: You won't want to leave it plugged into a red/blue socket as it won't be using your dedicated graphics card.*

Found a [thread on a similar problem](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkStation-Workstations/Lenovo-ThinkStation-P330-not-able-to-enter-BIOS-nor-PXE-boot/td-p/4412715)

Comment: I agree to try plugging into one of the on-board ports and see if that makes any difference. Also try that after taking out the 4 port card entirely and booting up without it plugged into the on-board ports (that may be overkill tho but if all else fails, simple enough). You might also have some sort of BIOS quick/fast boot enabled or perhaps an option to not show POST screen hot keys, etc. There should be a hot key like `F2` perhaps or another similar to the `F12` that takes you to the boot menu that will take you to BIOS, etc. Research online and try different keys then adjust BIOS options.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Good point - it may be booting faster than the screen can sync. I think the thread I looked at suggested `F1` as the BIOS button - I'll add that info in the answer.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT True - it's very possible some of the boot sequence is hidden. Most mobo's have the option to just show a *splash screen* instead of the boot sequence, and I know a lot of companies (Dell/HP/Viglen/etc) set a custom *splash screen* by default. Not sure about Lenovo though.

Answer (score 0):

Mine had dedicated graphics Quadro p620. I simply removed it. Then it booted to Bios like normal.

Yes its correct that it is booting up fast skipping BIOS and straight to login Screen of windows. Removing the dedicated graphic card resolved for me and i used the HDMI port.

Hope it helps someone.